# How to convert a column in data with date format to works it pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to use the date from the "fechas" column to make a analysis with pandas, can someone explain how to give the date format to that column.

```
                                               LEY         Unnamed: 3  \
0    Por medio de la cual se regula el uso del Desf...              Salud   
1    Por medio de la cual se adopta la estrategia S...              Salud   
2    Por medio de la cual se incentiva la adecuada ...              Salud   
3    Por la cual se decreta el presupuesto de renta...              Salud   
4     Por medio de la cual se modifican la Ley 73 d...              Salud   
5    Por medio de la cual se prohíben los procedimi...              Salud    


                 FECHA  
0        3 de agosto, 2017  
1       1 de febrero, 2017  
2       1 de febrero, 2017  
3       8 de febrero, 2017  
4       1 de febrero, 2017  
5       1 de febrero, 2017  

AÑO                            NOMBRE  \
0    2017.0                  Ley 1831 de 2017   
1    2017.0   Ley 1823 del 4 de enero de 2017   
2    2017.0   Ley 1822 del 4 de enero de 2017   
3    2016.0                  Ley 1815 de 2016   
4    2016.0  Ley 1805 del 4 de agosto de 2016   
5    2016.0   Ley 1799 del 25 de julio de2016
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dateparser` module is capable of handling numerous languages including french, russian, spanish, dutch and over 20 more. It also can recognize stuff like time zone abbreviations, etc.

```
import dateparser
dateparser.parse('3 de agosto, 2017')

# output - datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 3, 0, 0)
```

Now use the `dateparser` module with `pandas.apply()` to get what you want -

```
df['FECHA'] = df['FECHA'].apply(lambda x: dateparser.parse(x))
```

Or simply -

```
df['FECHA'].apply(dateparser.parse)
```

Or thanks to @jpp -

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=['FECHA'], date_parser=dateparser.parse)
```

**Output**

```
0   2017-08-03
1   2017-02-01
2   2017-02-01
3   2017-02-08
4   2017-02-01
5   2017-02-01
Name: FECHA, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I am working in Jupyter with Anaconda, and the module don't works, do you know some alternative ?

Comment: @SebastiánRamírez i just tested in Jupyter and it works fine

Comment: @jpp makes sense. Added it to ans

Comment: @SebastiánRamírez do a `pip install dateparser` to install the module and it should be fine

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan , I install dataparser but I get the next error 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 0: invalid start byte, what can I do?

Comment: @SebastiánRamírez Make sure your file is actually utf-8 encoded and not ANSI or something else

Comment: @Chris Okey, but in the case of AÑO column, what can I do to convert that to datetime64?